# Dynamic terms and conditions in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I created a two Checkout Terms & Conditions using `Admin -> Sales -> Terms & Conditions`.
How can I display only one of them depending on checkout grand total? 
For example, if Grand total less than $2000 then display first Terms & Conditions. And if Grand total more than $2000 then display second.
And second question is how can I insert an amount into the Terms & Conditions text?

Answer (score 1):

The code that filters agreements is located in the Mage_Checkout_Block_Agreements class:

```
public function getAgreements()
{
    if (!$this->hasAgreements()) {
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('checkout/options/enable_agreements')) {
            $agreements = array();
        } else {
            $agreements = Mage::getModel('checkout/agreement')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1);
        }
        $this->setAgreements($agreements);
    }
    return $this->getData('agreements');
}
```

This just returns a collection of active agreements within the allowed store scope. The template file calls this method (checkout/onepage/agreements.phtml):

```
<?php foreach ($this->getAgreements() as $_a): ?>
    <li>
        <div class="agreement-content"<?php echo ($_a->getContentHeight() ? ' style="height:' . $_a->getContentHeight() . '"' : '')?>>
            <?php if ($_a->getIsHtml()):?>
                <?php echo $_a->getContent() ?>
            <?php else:?>
                <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($_a->getContent())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <p class="agree">
            <input type="checkbox" id="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>" name="agreement[<?php echo $_a->getId()?>]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?>" class="checkbox" /><label for="agreement-<?php echo $_a->getId()?>"><?php echo $_a->getIsHtml() ? $_a->getCheckboxText() : $this->htmlEscape($_a->getCheckboxText()) ?></label>
        </p>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is probably to modify the template file. So I would imagine some logic like so:

```
$total = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
$agreement_name = ($total < 2000) ? 'lt2000' : 'gt2000';
$agreements = Mage::getModel('checkout/agreement')->getCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('name', $agreement_name);
}
<?php foreach ($agreements as $_a): ?>
    ....
```

In this example, you'd have two terms & conditions named 'lt2000' and 'gt2000' (or more -- with the same names but assigned to different store/website scopes). This code, however, doesn't account for additional agreements that may need to be displayed on the checkout page.

To answer you second question, [this](http://www.edmondscommerce.co.uk/magento/adding-custom-variables-to-magento-static-blocks/) is a good reference on how to add custom variables to static blocks. In your case, you just need to change the variable name and value to what you need and pass $_a->getContent() through the filter method. Then you'll be able to specify that variable in your terms & conditions text.

So, for example -- referencing the link, in your template code you can add:

```
$custom_vars = array('total'=>$total);
$filter = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
$filter->setVariables($custom_vars);
...
<?php echo $filter->filter($_a->getContent()) ?>
...
<?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($filter->filter($_a->getContent()))) ?>
```

And then you can add {{var total}} in your terms and conditions content in admin.

Comment: For anyone who comes across this solution the advice is correct, except that changing the frontend template will only change which terms and conditions are displayed at checkout. You also need to filter the terms you want to use via the helper function getRequiredAgreementIds in mage/checkout/helper/data.php. Otherwise you will display the correct terms but the submit function logic that uses the helper will complain that terms have not been met until you change the helper function too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the terms and conditions you have configured in admin by name you need to change the getAgreements function in the Mage Checkout Block Agreements class and the getRequiredAgreementIds function in the Mage Checkout Helper Data class.

For example, if you want terms for a retail customer group and terms for a wholesale customer group you would create the terms with the word RETAIL and WHOLESALE in the terms names in admin and then do something like below where we are filtering the terms based on the name.

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();

if ($groupId == 1)
{
$agreements = Mage::getModel('checkout/agreement')->getCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
->addFieldToFilter('name', array('like' => '%RETAIL%'));

}
```

Where group 1 is the retail group, duplicate the code for other groups.